# Import data from SQL to MongoDB. All or nothing

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, dbmigrate

I have the following architechture:
[image]

I Import data from a SQL datbase into a mongodb. I use the importer to migrate data into the mongodb that provides the data to a website via an API.

The importing can take a couple of minutes and if it fails I would like to be able to either rollback (it would be awsome to be able to rollback multiple imports) or drop the database/collections of the uncommited rows (if you think of it as SQL transactions).

I tried to import everything into a transactions collection that, on success, moved the data into the correct collection. This took way to much time to be performant. I also tried the solution of importing into a temp db and then swapping them. But then I run into problems if someone e.g. registers a new user on the website after the db-copy but before the importing is done (that user will be lost when swapping).

How can a perform an import in a safe way and not have the most basic concurrency problems?

**EDIT**:
To clarify the solution: 
I will run the importer in a cron job, at least once a day. I currently keep a timestamp for the latest synchronization and select everything that is newer than that from the SQL-db. Things will automagically appear in the SQL-db over time.

At the end of the importing I run a downloader that downloads all the images from urls in the SQL db.

I don't want to start a new sync before the images are downloaded since that could result in strange behaviour.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use node for the import process? I would think there are more highly-specialized tools for data migration than node that would be a better choice; https://github.com/compose/transporter for one

Comment: As @markthethomas mentioned, there is highly likely a specialised tool for doing this. Regarding rolling back, it's complicated because SQL is an ACID based database system and Mongo is a BASE based database system so they share very different characteristics with atomicity of transactions. Short story is you'll need to keep a track of what has been written to the Mongo DB and then trigger a delete of those documents if you need to roll back your SQL transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, where you need to move data between very different types of databases, you're going to tend to want something **really** reliable, robust, and, most-importantly, with its **primary** concern being transferring data and doing it well. Node.js is wonderful, but I would highly recommend you find some tool out there that is focused on only doing the transfer/mapping/etc. and use that regardless of what language/technology it uses. There's nothing about node.js, as much as I love it, that particularly recommends it for this sort of thing (e.g., it's best characteristics don't *necessarily* make it good for this sort of transfer/migration).

Better to find a **mature**, **well-developed** library that handles this sort of thing :)

Some tools/resources that turned up in my research:

- [mongify](https://github.com/anlek/mongify)
- [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/sql-comparison/)

Would love if people could suggest more in comments :)

Comment: I totally agree with mature, well developed. You can see my edits to get a better view of the problems at hand.